# Excel using win32com and python

Tags: python, win32com

I wanted to know how to read an entire column without iterating from an excel sheet using win32com client for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be to use the built in `Range` functionality through the `win32com.client` API. However, I'm not a big fan of it. I think the API is confusing and badly documented, and using it isn't very pythonic (but that's just me).

If efficiency is not an issue for you, you can use the excellent xlrd library. Like so:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbooks('Book1')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheel.col(1)
sheet.col(2)
# and so on...
```

That gives you the cell objects. To get pure values, use `sheet.col_values` (and there are a few other methods that are real nice to work with).

Just remember that xlrd stand for "excel read", so if you want to write to an excel file you need a different library called "xlwt" (which is also pretty good, though less so than xlrd in my opinion).

Comment: Yeah i did try writing this piece of code and was thinking , python can be used to write as less as possible so i was just wondering if there was anything that would just return me a list with the required column values without me having to write the iteration part.

Comment: You can use the xlrd library, wait a second I'll add an example

Comment: There. hope that helps!

Comment: Conceptually, I think OP is looking for a way to retrieve an entire range "in one go", like retrieving a result set using `SELECT` from a database. That is, any "iterating" that must be done during retrieval is handled *before* it gets to Python. In the database case, the SQL engine may be iterating under the covers, but all you see is a *single* "return value", that happens to contain multiple values within it. So for Excel, OP is looking to specify a range, then grab all the values "at once" into, say, a tuple. This may or may not be possible; I don't know COM well enough.

Comment: All that being said, I don't see *why* iteration needs to be avoided in the first place. Perhaps it's because accessing Excel via COM cell by cell is notoriously slow. Operating on an Excel range is vastly faster than operating on one cell at a time. But reading the file directly via `xlrd` (and not involving COM at all) is usually fast enough.

Comment: @John Y, I think that xlrd and the win32com iteration are perfectly fine, and I agree that there's no reason to avoid it. the COM technique is decent, and xlrd probably does the same iteration in some optimized way. In the past, I used both the COM library and xlrd for different projects, it really depends on what you need. Furthermore, if there's a need for a fast querying and you deal with a large database, then you shouldn't use excel in the first place but rather use an SQL database

Comment: As i am writing and reading simultaneously i will currently use win32com. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Well, at some level, sure there's going to be iteration of some kind. But it's fastest if you can let Excel do the heavy lifting (via COM, but using range operations; i.e. the Excel program itself takes the role of the "SQL engine"). If you have to do the iterating at a "high level" (in this case with Python), then reading the file directly is faster than COM simply because there is overhead associated with the COM machinery (Python communicating with Windows communicating with the running Excel instance). I am a huge fan of `xlrd` but there's nothing particularly optimized about it.

Comment: @John Y, you mean you think the best way would be to use COM commands to manipulate the excel because those are natural to the COM environment? while I do agree with you, I would still prefer using the win32com API or the the xlrd over it by a longshot. Both methods beat VB macros in both readability and flexibility, and like I said, if it's exceptionally large than you would rather use a DB than an excel

Comment: No, I mean the fastest is to use Excel's own range operations, via COM. If you use `win32com` you are still using COM. To me, using Python and `win32com` is more-or-less equivalent to using VBScript. Whether you use Python or VBScript to control an active instance of Excel, iterating cell-by-cell is very slow. But doing Excel range operations is pretty fast. `xlrd` is something **completely** and **utterly** different than `win32com`. With `xlrd`, the Excel program is not involved at all, and there is no COM. You can use `xlrd` on any Python-capable platform, such as Linux.

Comment: Yeah I understood what you ment. I agree, but like I said, python is more flexible than excel operations and if you're looking for efficiency then don't use excel

Comment: This answer is wrong. You **can** access column values without iterating using Range. It is bad advice for anyone to use `Cells` especially beginners who are likely viewing this page.

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson Yes, you're right. I took that part out entirely. I'm not a big fan of using the COM API anyway, and your answer shows that method so there's no reason for duplicity (you got +1 from me). I wouldn't say however that you're **not** iterating when using Range, because, well you clearly are (a list comprehension, and it's only to extract the pure values, but its all the same really).

Comment: @Yuvi Cool. I agree that COM is tricky some times but it is a great tool to use for data exploration by an analyst but definitely not for a developer unless she is building a native tool in Excel for an end user.

Answer (score 14):

You can read an entire column without iterating from a sheet using the `Range` collection. You should **never use `Cells` if performacne is any concern**. Python uses the win32com module to interact with the Excel COM library. Whenever you use Python and COM (Excel, PowerPoint, Acess, ADODB, etc.) one of your biggest performance constraints will be IO between COM and Python. With the `Range` method you only make one COM method call while with `Cells` you make one for each row. This would also be faster if you were doing the same in VBA or .NET

In the following test I created a worksheet with 10 random characters in cells A1 through A2000. I then extracted these values into lists using both Range and Cells.

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
s = app.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

def GetValuesByCells():
    startTime = time.time()
    vals = [s.Cells(r,1).Value for r in range(1,2001)]
    return time.time() - startTime

def GetValuesByRange():
    startTime = time.time()
    vals = [v[0] for v in s.Range('A1:A2000').Value]
    return time.time() - startTime

>>> GetValuesByRange()
0.03600001335144043

>>> GetValuesByCells()
5.27400016784668
```

In this case Range is 2 orders of magnitude faster (146x) faster than Cells. Note that the Range method returns a 2D list where each inner list is a row. The list iteration transposes `vals` into a 2D list where the inner list is a column.

Comment: OK, I'm upvoting this even though, in its current form, I don't really consider it an answer.  To me, this is a very long comment.  Why I think it still deserves an upvote is that it is ultimately more useful and more helpful than either of the other answers presented so far (despite yuvi's being accepted already).  The code snippet shown here clearly comes the closest to illustrating how to "read an entire column without iterating ... using `win32com`".

Comment: I just looked back on this answer and modified it to answer the original question

Comment: I wonder how well it does against `xlrd`. If the differences are miniscule, then xlrd would be a clear winner

Comment: @yuvi: I haven't tested extensively myself, but I think it depends to a large extent on the nature of the data and the nature of what you're trying to do. The bigger and more complicated the workbook, the bigger the advantage Excel will have, in sheer loading time alone. The more you can rely on Excel itself to do the heavy lifting (via its ranges and its calculation engine), the bigger the advantage Excel will have. Just make sure you make as few and as productive COM calls as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) library? From the documentation:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='file.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name='Sheet1')
columns = ws.columns()
```

There's also support for iterators and other goodies.