# Trying to read rows from an Excel file

Tags: excel, python-2.7, rows

I am trying to read a few rows from an `.xlsx` file and save the information to a list. The data I want is on `sheet1` which is the only sheet. The code below seems to open the file ok and counts that there are 6 columns. This is correct.

But when I try to get python to read the data in the first row, here is what I get: `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Ultimately I would like the code to read the first row and the last 10 rows of the file. I have also included a snippet of by `.xlsx` file so you can see the set up there:

[image]

The version of python I have is 2.7.12.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import string

scrExcelFile = r"D:/python_class/Semester_Project/index2.xlsx"
exclApp   = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
exclWrkBk = exclApp.Workbooks.open(scrExcelFile)
exclsheet = exclWrkBk.Sheets(1)

lastCol = exclsheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
print "The last comlumn number is %r" % lastCol

headers = []
for row in range(1):
    for col in range(lastCol):
        headers.append(row)
print headers
```

Comment: When you use range(1) you are reading row 0 first. May be that's the issue?

Comment: Also, you're appending `row` to `headers` over and over, instead of getting the actual value from the sheet and then appending that.

Comment: I have tried a few different range values. When I tried range 0, I get an error, When I tried range 2 I get [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1].....for some reason its not reading whats in the cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't take an account that range in python starts from 0 and in excel rows, columns starts from 1. So your code should be like this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import string

scrExcelFile = r"D:111.xlsx"
exclApp   = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
exclWrkBk = exclApp.Workbooks.open(scrExcelFile)
exclsheet = exclWrkBk.Sheets(1)

lastCol = exclsheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
print ("The last comlumn number is %r" % lastCol)

headers=[]
for r in range(1,lastCol+1):
    headers.append(exclsheet.Cells(1,r).Value)
print (headers)
```

In addition to this check this question in order to improve performance: [Excel using win32com and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575043/excel-using-win32com-and-python)

Comment: When I entered in your code to try it out I got [1,1,1,1,1,1]  Something is still not right

Comment: the updated code mostly worked, it didnt get the last column but its not a list of 0s anymore! thank you so much! I got a 'u' in front of each element in the list. I have not seen that before, what does it mean?

Comment: To get last column, change `r in range(1,lastCol)` to `r in range(1,lastCol+1)`. The 'u' in front of the string values means the string has been represented as unicode. It is a way to represent more characters than normal ascii can manage. See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html, specifically the 'unicode type' section